# Handling of Topic Drill Downs in Databases

Tags: database-design

I have a requirement wherein I have to set up a drill down feature.

For example:
There is a tab in a shopping website "Men". Now if we click on Men we will get more topics like "Clothing", "Accessories" etc. When we click on "Clothing" we again get "Tees", "Polos", "Shirts", "Jeans". Again if we click on "Tees" we get further options of "Plain", "Graphic" etc.

So a specialization kind of thing comes into picture

```
  Men --> Clothing --> Tees --> Graphics
```

I am not able to figure out an efficient way how to handle these types of feature in a database. Though this is present everywhere and is quite common, but still figuring out a way to implement this is getting tougher.

Can someone help me with some pointers so that I can do some research in the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wanting to store a tree structure. This is a bit awkward with databases, but it's definitely possible. Here's a link which explains how: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ The "Nested Set Model" part is what you're looking for.

Applying that model to your scenario, you would get a table that looks something like this:
[image]

And a conceptual model for the first 3 levels that looks something like this (please excuse my MS Paint drawing skills): [image]
Obviously you would have more nodes, but it's the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks Joe. This seems to be quite informative and helpful.